# How to read one \t from \ t\t written in a file using regular expressions in c

Tags: c

I have written the following code to read data from the file whose data is as follows:

```
Anita Shah  F   Nationalist Congress Party  NCP
Shobha Oza  F   Indian National Congress    INC
Mahendra Hordiya    M   Bharatiya Janata Party  BJP
Rakesh Bhardwaj M       IND
Sanjay Shukla   M       INC
```

And the code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    char cand_name[50],cand_sex,partyname[60],partyabbre[5];
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node NODE;

NODE* getnode(void)
{
    NODE *nnode;
    nnode=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    nnode->next=NULL;
    return nnode;
}

void display(NODE *head)
{
    NODE *cur;
    cur=head;
    int i=1;
    while(cur!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d. %s\t%c\t%s\t%s\n",i,cur->cand_name,cur->cand_sex,cur->partyname,cur->partyabbre);
        fflush(stdout);
        cur=cur->next;
        i++;
    }   
}

main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    NODE *start,*cur;
    fp=fopen("data.txt","r");
    cur=getnode();
    start=cur;
    fscanf(fp,"%[^\t]\t%c\t%[^\t]\t%s\n",cur->cand_name,&cur->cand_sex,cur->partyname,cur->partyabbre);
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        cur->next=getnode();
        cur=cur->next;
        fscanf(fp,"%[^\t]\t%c\t%[^\t]\t%s\n",cur->cand_name,&cur->cand_sex,cur->partyname,cur->partyabbre); 
    }
    display(start);
}
```

For 4th entry in file, I want `cur->prtyname` to be blank, but my code is taking `cur->partyname` as IND.

Comment: `fscanf` is most probably not the right tool for this problem. It simply ignores "fields" left empty. Read the whole line using `fgets`, and tear it apart into fields, using `strchr`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgets` to read an entire line. Parse the line with `strcspn`. Using an array ( `sub[3][100]`)for the substrings simplifies the while loop .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void) {
    char tab[] = { "one\x9\x9three"};
    char sub[3][100] = { "\0"};
    int length = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    int used = 0;
    int item = 0;

    length = strlen ( tab);
    while ( used < length) {
        offset = strcspn ( &tab[used], "\t");//find a tab
        if ( offset < 99) {
            memcpy ( sub[item], &tab[used], offset);
            sub[item][offset] = '\0';
        }
        else {//substring longer than available space of 100
            memcpy ( sub[item], &tab[used], 99);
            sub[item][99] = '\0';
        }
        used += offset + 1;
        item++;
        if ( item >= 3) {//too many items. only 3 provided for
            break;
        }
    }
    //print the three substrings.
    printf ( "sub[0] %s\n", sub[0]);
    printf ( "sub[1] %s\n", sub[1]);
    printf ( "sub[2] %s\n", sub[2]);
    return 0;
}
```